# Where can one find an up to date copy of sections 212-215 of the Housing Act 2004?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-research, statutes

Legislation.gov.uk has up to date copies of many laws as they are most recently amended, but not of the Housing Act 2004. Where can an up to date version of this law be found online or in person?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know where you looked, but the [Housing Act 2004](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2004/34/contents) on legislation.gov.uk is up to date according to its header:

> [the] Housing Act 2004 is up to date with all changes known to be in force on or before 12 January 2023. There are changes that may be brought into force at a future date.

Sections 212 to 215 fall within [Part 6, Chapter 4](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2004/34/part/6/chapter/4?timeline=false) of the Act.

With hindsight, you may be looking at an earlier version.  So for awareness, if the entry's header is:

- green, then it is up to date. Any provisional amendments (i.e. yet to be enacted) there might be can be found using the "view outstanding changes" drop down option if there is one.
- red, then there are changes yet to be made which can be found via the "view outstanding changes" drop down option.
- blue, it's either the original version that has not had any amendments, or it's an earlier version that can be navigated to/from by selecting the the tick box "show timeline of changes" and the sliding calendar above the header.

Comment: Ah right! I was looking at the downloadable PDF King’s printer version, which seems to lack many or all of the effective amendments.

Comment: @Seekinganswers Yes, the PDF generally only shows the original version of an Act, before any amendments are made. You have to use the online version to see the amended version.